# Expo: How to purchase In-App product in revenue cat

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-console, revenuecat

I have added in app products in play console and also imported them to revenue cat dashboard, i am also fetching and displaying these products in my app, now i know that there is a method called `Purchases.purchaseProduct` but i dont know how to use it.

For `Purchases.purchasePackage` method we get **customerInfo** object back on successfull purchase but what do we get or how do we know user successfully bought the product, i can only see  `Purchases.purchaseProduct` in documentation

Here is the documentation that i am referring to

[Making Purchases](https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/making-purchases)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.